# How to convert elapsed time string to seconds in Python

Tags: python, date, time

Does anyone know if there is an "easy" function which will convert the following elapsed time string to seconds?
2d1h39m53s

Depending on how much time has elapsed, not all the fields will be present.

I've looked at strptime and datetime but nothing seemed to fit the bill without writing my own function for this.  Just looking to save some time.
Thx

Comment: there are other modules for date/time - maybe one of them can parse it: [6 Python datetime libraries](https://opensource.com/article/18/4/python-datetime-libraries)

Comment: you can also try regex: `re.search('(?:(\d+)d)?(?:(\d+)h)?(?:(\d+)m)?(?:(\d+)s)?', item).groups()` to work with `'2d1h39m53s', '1h39m53s', '39m53s', '53s'`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it to days before to clearly verify the runtime. After the two defs below just write 'tic()' at the start point in your code where you want count and 'toc()' at the end point, and it will give you a clear time data to read. Hope it helps.

```
import time
import math


def tic():
    global startTime_for_tictoc
    startTime_for_tictoc = time.time()


def toc():
    if 'startTime_for_tictoc' in globals():
        tf = time.time() - startTime_for_tictoc;
        if tf < 60:
            print("\nElapsed time: %f seconds.\n" % tf)
        elif 60 < tf < 3600:
            mm = math.floor(tf/60)
            ss = tf - (60*mm)
            print("\nElapsed time: %d minute(s) and %f seconds.\n" % (mm, ss))
        elif 3600 < tf < 86400:
            hh = math.floor(tf/3600)
            mm = math.floor((tf-(hh*3600))/60)
            ss = tf - (hh*3600) - (60*mm)
            print("\nElapsed time: %d hour(s) %d minute(s) and %f seconds.\n" % (hh, mm, ss))
        elif tf > 86400:
            dd = math.floor(tf/86400)
            hh = math.floor((tf-(dd*86400))/3600)
            mm = math.floor((tf-(dd*86400)-(hh*3600))/60)
            ss = tf - (86400*dd) - (hh*3600) - (60*mm)
            print("\nElapsed time: %d day(s) %d hour(s) %d minute(s) and %f seconds.\n" % (dd, hh, mm, ss))
    else:
        print("\nToc: start time not set")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a function out there but this will get the job done. Will work with values such as "2d1h53s" as well.

```
d = []
h = []
m = []
s = []
sd = 0
sh = 0
sm = 0
ss = 0

str = "2d1h39m53s"

i = 0
if str.find("d") > 0:
    i = str.find("d")
    d.append(str[0:i])
    str = str[i:]
if str.find("h") > 0:
    i = str.find("h")
    h.append(str[1:i])
    str = str[i:]
if str.find("m") > 0:
    i = str.find("m")
    m.append(str[1:i])
    str = str[i:]
if str.find("s") > 0:
    i = str.find("s")
    s.append(str[1:i])
    str = str[i:]

try:
    sd = float(d[0]) * 24 * 60 * 60
except:
    sd = 0
try:
    sh = float(h[0]) * 60 * 60
except:
    sh = 0
try:
    sm = float(m[0]) * 60
except:
    sm = 0
try:
    ss = float(s[0])
except:
    ss = 0

print("seconds")
sec = sd + sh + sm + ss
print(sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your datetime has exactly the given format you could do the following:

```
import re
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

split_strings = ['D', 'h','m','s']
def datestring_to_seconds(datestring):
    values_and_units = [(int(string[:-1]), string[-1]) for string in [re.search(f"([0-9]+){split_string}", 
                            f"{datestring}".replace('d', 'D')).group(0) for split_string in split_strings]]
    return reduce(lambda x,y : x+y, [np.timedelta64(*x) for x in values_and_units])/np.timedelta64(1, 's')
```

result

```
datestring_to_seconds("2d1h39m53s")
178793.0
```

Some explanation:
First search in the string for any to a match of up to two digits in front of one of the `split_strings` (e.g. `39m`) then we convert this to a tuple `(39, "m")`. We perform this operation with every string in `split_strings` and save the result in the list `values_and_units`, which looks in our special case like this:

```
[(2, 'D'), (1, 'h'), (39, 'm'), (53, 's')]
```

Each element of these can now be casted to a numpy timedelta64. The reduce operation adds up all the timedeltas and dividing by a `np.timedelta64(1, 's')` gives us a float with the desired seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure python solution.

```
import re

s = '2d1h39m53s'
d = {'d':86400,'h':3600, 'm':60, 's':1}

secs = 0
m = re.match(r'(\d+)([dhms])', s)

while m is not None:
    secs += int(m.group(1)) * d[m.group(2)]
    s = re.sub(r'\d+[dhms]', '', s, 1)
    m = re.match(r'(\d+)([dhms])', s)

print(secs)


print(secs)
```

Prints: 178793

EDIT: To use match.end() to locate beginning of next search. Not destructive of string, s, and a cleaner solution.

```
import re

s = '2d1h39m53s'
d = {'d':86400,'h':3600, 'm':60, 's':1}

secs = 0
pat = re.compile('(\d+)([dhms])')

m = pat.search(s)

while m is not None:
    pos = m.end()
    secs += int(m.group(1)) * d[m.group(2)]
    m = pat.search(s, pos)

print(secs)
```

Comment: All great answers, thank you.  This one by Chris worked great.  I just added weeks and months also to string. Thank you again